# Query that create Case (90%) – control (10%) that "MEMBERSHIP_STATUS" be distributed proportionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below that returns me the clients of the company with Case (90%) – control (10%), who didnt bought 'FISH'.

```
SELECT
    CAD.ID,
    CASE WHEN NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY CLI.ID) = 1 THEN 'CONTROL' ELSE 'CASE' END AS CASE_CONTROL,
    CAD.DES_CAMPAIGN,
    CAD.ID_CAMPAIGN
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, SSN,
           '202306_JOB_10927412049' AS DES_CAMPAIGN,
                'Z-2DGQETF014' AS ID_CAMPAIGN
                    FROM TB_CLIENTS) AS CLI

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TB_ORDERS WHERE ID = CLI.ID AND PRODUCT = 'FISH')
```

But, i have a column called MEMBERSHIP_STATUS in TB_CLIENTS, with a lot of types of status.
I want that query return the case-control equally distributed by MEMBERSHIP_STATUS.

If the query returns me 100 lines, where:

50 of them has MEMBERSHIP_STATUS = 'Gold', 30 of them has MEMBERSHIP_STATUS = 'Platina', 20 of them has MEMBERSHIP_STATUS = 'Diamond'

I want that my control (10%) contains 5 gold clients, 3 platina clients and 2 diamond clients.

Note:

i have a lot of MEMBERSHIP_STATUS.

Thanks guys!

I tried something with dynamic SQL, but my server doesnt support it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @jarlh i'm using in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Query Studio (based on SQL Server 2016). Also, thanks for the advice of minimal reproducible example. :)

Comment: Maybe you want `NTILE(10) OVER(PARTITON BY CLI.MEMBERSHIP_STATUS ORDER BY CLI.ID)`? Sample data and desired results would help.